# Set consequent non na values to NA

Tags: r

Set every non-NA value that has a non-NA value to "his left" to `NA`.

#### Data

```
a <- c(3,2,3,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,2,1,4,NA)

[1]  3  2  3 NA NA  1 NA NA  2  1  4 NA
```

#### Desired Output

```
[1]  3 NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA  2 NA NA NA
```

#### My working but ugly solution:

```
IND   <- !(is.na(a)) & data.table::rleidv(!(is.na(a))) %>% duplicated
a[IND]<- NA
a
```

There's gotta be a better solution ...

Comment: `a[!is.na(lag(a))]<-NA`

Comment: Stephen would you like to answer this. That's the winner I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK for brevity...

```
a[!is.na(dplyr::lag(a))]<-NA
a
[1]  3 NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA  2 NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively,

```
a[-1][diff(!is.na(a)) == 0] <- NA; a
# [1]  3 NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA  2 NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do a simple `ifelse` statement where you add your vector with a lagged vector `a`. If the result is NA then the value should remain the same. Else, NA, i.e.

```
ifelse(is.na(a + dplyr::lag(a)), a, NA)
#[1]  3 NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA  2 NA NA NA
```