# R: Keep first values in time series after NA and set 3 consecutive values to NA

Tags: r, time-series, na

I have a data frame with many time series in the columns (example for one series in col1). I would like to go through each time series and keep the first value which appears after a NA and set *only the consecutive 3 values to NA* (example of the desired result in col2). Ideally, this should work for all or specified (e.g. [2:30]) columns in the data frame.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48585280/6432171) does not take the condition of only the 3 consecutive values to NA into account.

**Sample data**

```
df <- data.frame(
col1 = c(7.00, NA, NA, 1.00, 2.00, 5.00, NA, 5.00, 7.00, NA, NA, 1.00, NA, 2.00, NA, NA, 1.00, 3.00, 4.00, 5.00, 6.00, 7.00, NA, 7.00, NA),
col2 = c(7.00, NA, NA, 1.00, NA, NA, NA, 5.00, NA, NA, NA, 1.00, NA, 2.00, NA, NA, 1.00, NA, NA, NA, 6.00, NA, NA, 7.0, NA),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is row 22 correct? I expected a `7` output, but you have an `NA`. It seems to be the sixth row since the last `NA` in `col1`.

Comment: @JonSpring. Thank you, Jon. Great solution. But, indeed, my example is "correct". I did not make it clear enough in my question: In the case if there are more than 4 valid values after an NA, the 5th should be treated as if it was the first after an NA.

Comment: Aha. No that wasn't clear. From the wording it sounds like only rows 2:4 of each group following an `NA` should be `NA`, but it sounds like you'd like to apply the same pattern to rows 6:8, 10:12, etc. Modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: @JonSpring: Awesome. That does the trick. Thank you very much. Is it possible to run this for all columns or specified columns in a data frame?

Comment: Would the # / NA logic work separately for each column, or would they all base off of one "key" column?  What output would you expect if the original data looks like this? `df <- data.frame(colA = c(7.0, NA,  NA, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0), colB = c(2.0, 2.0, NA,  NA, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: Every column should be treated separately - as if it was the "only" one df <- data.frame(colA = c(7.0, NA, NA, 1.0, NA, NA, NA, 5.0), colB = c(2.0, NA, NA, NA, 6.0, NA, NA, NA), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using `dplyr`.

First I make a new group each time we have a valid value that follows an `NA`. Then within each group, I set the 2nd through 4th rows to be `NA`, otherwise uses `col1`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(new_grp = if_else(!is.na(col1) & is.na(lag(col1)), 1, 0),
         grp = cumsum(new_grp)) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  # Modified below per OP clarification: treat each group of 4 entries
  #   following an NA like the first four, with one value and then 3 NAs.
  #   Uses modulo 4, where any row with a remainder of 2, 3, or 0 (ie row 4, etc.) will get NA
  mutate(col2b = case_when(row_number() %% 4 %in% c(2:3, 0)  ~ NA_real_,
                          TRUE ~ col1)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Output:

```
row col1 col2 col2b
1   7   7   7
2   NA  NA  NA
3   NA  NA  NA
4   1   1   1
5   2   NA  NA
6   5   NA  NA
7   NA  NA  NA
8   5   5   5
9   7   NA  NA
10  NA  NA  NA
11  NA  NA  NA
12  1   1   1
13  NA  NA  NA
14  2   2   2
15  NA  NA  NA
16  NA  NA  NA
17  1   1   1
18  3   NA  NA
19  4   NA  NA
20  5   NA  NA
21  6   6   6
22  7   NA  NA   # Modified per OP clarification
23  NA  NA  NA
24  7   7   7
25  NA  NA  NA
```

#### Edit: Applying to multiple / all columns

If all your columns are of the same type, this should work to convert all the columns at once. It works by using `tidyr` to gather the data from wide to "long" format, then performs the same calculation as before, and then spreads back to a wide format.

```
df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::gather(col, value, -row) %>%
  group_by(col) %>%

  mutate(new_grp = if_else(!is.na(value) & is.na(lag(value)), 1, 0),
         grp = cumsum(new_grp)) %>%
  group_by(col, grp) %>%
  mutate(value = case_when(row_number() %% 4 %in% c(2:3, 0)  ~ NA_real_,
                           TRUE ~ value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  tidyr::spread(col, value) %>%
  select(-row, -new_grp, -grp)
```

If your data frame uses different types, I think it gets more complicated, unless there's a simpler alternative I'm missing. I started with an approach that uses "tidyeval" to let you programmatically change one specified column using a function. The last step after this could use `purrr` to apply the function to all columns.

```
NA_2to4 <- function(df_name, col_to_change) {
  col_quo <- enquo(col_to_change)
  df_name %>%
    mutate(new_grp = if_else(!is.na(!!col_quo) & is.na(lag(!!col_quo)), 1, 0),
         grp = cumsum(new_grp)) %>%
    group_by(grp) %>%
    mutate(!!col_quo := case_when(row_number() %% 4 %in% c(2:3, 0)  ~ NA_real_,
                             TRUE ~ !!col_quo)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-new_grp, -grp)
}
```

Here's how you could apply that to specific columns:

```
df %>% 
  NA_2to4(colA) %>%
  NA_2to4(colB)
```

I presume there's a way to use `purr::map` to apply to all columns, but I'm not sure the syntax in this moment.

Comment: Yes, all data in the columns are of the same type. If I use your first code, I get a "0" in the first row, and then a "0" every 4th row. And this for all columns. See this input data for you code: df <- data.frame(
col1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
col2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
col3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
col4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)